# Apache Storm: Nimbus not starting on Port 6627

Tags: java, apache-storm

I can't see anything on port 6627 after starting Nimbus. I am getting the Connection Refused error. Following errors are thrown in Nimbus Log:

```
6899 [main] ERROR com.smarterme.intake.EmbeddedTopologyRunner - Toplogy submitting failed.....org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:38)
    at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:116)**
```

Do you guys have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "nimbus" to /etc/hosts file as alias to 127.0.0.1 and localhost.

Make sure **iptables** is not the issue from the host you are
trying to run or Most likely there is something wrong in your ~/.storm/storm.yaml

Go through below link,hope this could help you.

http://storm.apache.org/about/deployment.html