# Apache storm nimbus: connection refused

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, apache-storm

I'm facing this problem when I have installed Apache Storm on two machines on AWS EC2 Amazon

storm list

```
Running: java -client -apache-storm-0.9.4/bin backtype.storm.command.list
53149 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.thrift - Connecting to Nimbus at 172.31.32.97:6627
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: Your error message is hard to read.  Put 4 spaces before each line and it will format nicely.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409191/apache-storm-nimbus-not-starting-on-port-6627/29097376#29097376  Hope this could help you.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? It would be best if you could provide your solution to this question in case anybody winds up at this post in the future and wants to know how it was solved.

Comment: I solved the problem because it was a security issue with my AWS machines on Amazon that I didn't notice it. Zookeeper was not communicated with other machines on port 2181 because it was closed.

Comment: More information on what you did to get it working would be good. Post it as an answer and mark it as the correct one. I've got the same issue and need to resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Nimbus could not connect with Zookeeper nodes on other machines due to the ports of Nimbus and Zookeeper were not opened .The security was the problem on the machines and the port 2181 of Zookeeper was closed on machines.
I solved the problem by setting the ports of Nimbus and 
zookeepers are open.
If you need more description about the answer, just write comment.